# Solving a recurrence relation using Smoothness Rule

Tags: algorithm, recursion, discrete-mathematics, recurrence

Consider this recurrence relation: `x(n) = x(n/2) + n`, for `n > 1` and `x(1) = 0`.
Now here the method of back substitution will struggle for values of `n` not powers of `2`, so it is best known here is to use the smoothness rule to solve this types of questions, and when we use the smoothness rule, where we will solve for `n = 2^k` (for n = values powers of 2) we will have a solution of `x(n) = 2n - 1`.
However, if we use the method of backward substitution, this recurrence relation will have a solution!
`x(n) = x(n/2) + n = x(n/4) + n/2 + n = x(n/8) + n/4 + n/2 + n = x(n/16) + n/8 + n/4 + n/2 + n = ....`
where the pattern is
`x(n) = x(n/i) + n/(i/2) + n/(i/4) + n/(i/8) + n/(i/16) + ...`
which will stop when n = 1 (i.e when i = n) and in this case
`x(n) = x(n/n) + n/(n/2) + n/(n/4) + n/(n/8) + n/(n/16) + ... = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... = 2^(n+1) - 1`
which is two different answers!
So please I am so confused here because in the textbook (Introduction to Analysis and Design of Algorithms by Anany Levitin) it is mention that we should use here the smoothness rule, but as you can see I have solved it exactly by the method of backward substitution where the method was expected here to struggle but nothing has happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... = 2^(n+1) - 1` is false.
That is since the number of elements in the left series is `log n` so the sum is `2^(log n + 1) - 1`, which is exactly `2n - 1`.
The reason there are `log n` elements is that `n/(2^i) = 1` (the last element of the series is 1) when `i = log n`.